# Windows 10 update to version 2004 causes instabilities with Intel Network Adapters

Tags: drivers, windows-update, windows-10-v2004

*An update can be found further down in the question*

This week I had to update my Business version of Windows 10, it's the 2004 version of the operating system that had some updates. This update was performed automatically over night. When I came back in to the office I noticed that my Intel Converged (X540 T2) and I211 Adapters was disabled. When enabling them, they drop in and out for a few minutes, then drop connectivity completely. When I run diagnostics I observe that it complains that the IP Configuration has issues and that it cannot fix it.

I've tried to re-install the drivers and reboot, update the drivers to the newest ones from september 2020 and uninstall them and reboot (to see if Windows could fix this somehow).

I'm no expert on Windows, and after being tossed around in the Windows Support Jungle, I ended up talking to someone who told me I had to pay for support. I don't think it is reasonable to pay for something Windows seemingly have caused.

So he told me to read online for solutions, and there are no solutions I can find that adress this issue -  some are older suggestions with the same solutions I just described above.

So I haven't been able to do my job this whole week because of this, and I wonder how I can solve this issue, since Microsoft clearly doesn't want to involve themselves in this.

I can also see that some of the staffs computers drivers fail after updates and it takes me a long time to solve these issues. Especially scanner drivers have problems

I am the IT administrator in a small public institution with a limited budget and Microsoft is kind of forced on me, since we need their products to communicate with other institutions.

---

**Update**: It seems that Windows clears part of the IP-configuration at random times during the day. Sometimes it clears everything, and some times only either DNS or Default Gateway is cleared. I cannot begin to understand how this works. I can only see this on network adapters through cable, the WiFi is working fine.

---

Does anyone here have any suggestion as to what I can try? I have little experience with Microsoft, but I get the feeling that they have monopoly on software solutions almost everywhere and it is frustrating when they abuse this position to force us to pay.

Comment: Have you downloaded the updated driver Intel (presumably released), if there isn’t an updated driver, you will have to roll back to the previous version (or have someone who can do that do it for you)

Comment: Did you try raising a Support Case with Intel?  That may be an approach to try.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, I tried updating to the latest drivers from Intel but no difference. I also tried to roll back the update and driver. To me it looks like a configuration issue somewhere - but I cannot figure out what was changed by the update.

John: No I haven't tried that, but going that route seems unrealistic, Intel has never helped on support in the past - they just point to re-sellers and forums.